# Rate of Change in the variances in PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, variance, density-function

I have four data sets with probability density function (PDF)s as shown in the figure. Each of the PDFs has different mean (near to zero) and different variance. I want to derive the rate of change in the variances. 
One of my thought is
1. Take log of each PDF
2. Take first derivative to see where is the maximum
3. Take Full Width Half Maximum (FWHM)
4. Then calculate the rate of change

But I am not sure if I am in the right track? Please help.

[image: PDF1]

Comment: Why would you want to take log in the first step?

Comment: I want to normalize all PDFs since those are not all zero mean. I might be wrong. Can you suggest any other approach please.

Comment: Just don't take the log, the rest is fine (since you appear to be from engineering or physical science related field).

Comment: Thanks a lot @LeeDavidChungLin. I was more interested in mathematical formulation rather calculating values only especially the rate of change.